# Creating new feature branch from another feature branch?

Tags: git

I have a feature A (not likely to be dropped) that is still not considered completed and may change before will be merged into Develop. I want to start working on a new feature B in the meantime but feature B would rely on changes done in feature A so I want to branch from A instead of Develop. What is the "best" way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get `featureA` merged as soon as possible.

In the meantime, it's ok to create `featureB` from `featureA`.
However, don't create a pull request for `featureB` before `featureA` is completed.
The reason is that when somebody reviews `featureB` before `featureA`,
they will see all the changes in both branches.
After `featureA` is merged,
you can create a pull request,
and reviewers will only see the new changes.

While working on `featureB`, if you fixed something in `featureA`,
you can merge from `featureA`, or rebase on top of it if you prefer.

Comment: the part about pull requests is specific to github, not git